# How to get all the vital information related to my app(like crash and error logs) which is present on Google Playstore

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play

I need all the information related to my android app which is present on the google playstore(like crashes etc). Is it possible to fetch this data from google playstore or google console. and insert that data into a table in GCP or AWS and how?

Comment: This isn't really something that can be answered easily over stack overflow.  But the way that we did this at my company was to create a an application that ran nightly that pulled the download, installation, report, etc... information from the google buckets here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=financial_export&rd=1#export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really something that can be answered easily over stack overflow.  But the way that we did this at my company was to create a an application that ran nightly that pulled the download, installation, report, etc... information from Cloud Storage.  This is how you can access the data, but determining how the application should work, when it should run, and where the data is stored is really up to you. We did it with a nightly job that fetched, parsed, and stored the results in a database.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=financial_export&rd=1#export

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to contact them for getting the app crash and ANR data

Comment: That URL I posted above has information regarding crash and ANR data.  It looks like they expose that in their buckets for you to consume with their APIs.  Because of the fact that they expose it, I don't think contacting them is going to do anything.  I think the expectation is to use the APIs they expose.